# Get values into list of tuples

Tags: python, list, yaml, terraform, tuples

I have the following structure which is produced by yamldecode(file("myfile.yaml")) and I use Terraform.

```
[
  {
    "name" = "A"
    "number" = "1"
    "description" = "Bla"
  },
  {
    "name" = "B"
    "number" = "2"
    "description" = "Bla"
  },
]
```

Initial yaml looks like:

```
test:
  - name: "A"
    number: '1'
    description: "Bla"
  - name: "B"
    number: '2'
    description: "Bla"
```

I need to get values from all maps in a list of tuples. Please advice

Expected result:

```
("A", 1, "Bla"), ("B", 2, "Bla")
```

Comment: Order of elements should remain the same.

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? You also certainly don't get a value with `=` from `yamldecode`…?! Or we're not talking about [tag:python] here. How about `[tuple(i.values()) for i in lst]`?

Answer (score 1):

You can load YAML file as dict using pyyaml library and iterate over data.

Install pyyaml using  `pip install pyyaml`:

```py
import yaml

with open("test.yaml", "r") as stream:
    data_list_dict = yaml.safe_load(stream)

output_list = []
for data_dict in data_list_dict['test']:
    output_list.append(tuple(data_dict.values()))

print(output_list)
```

Output:

```
[('1', 'Bla', 'A'), ('2', 'Bla', 'B')]
```

Or

```py
import yaml

with open("test.yaml", "r") as stream:
    data_list_dict = yaml.safe_load(stream)

output_list = [tuple(data_dict.values()) for data_dict in data_list_dict['test']]
print(output_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

If order is important you can do the following:

```
locals {
   
    test = [
  {
    "name" = "A"
    "number" = "1"
    "description" = "Bla"
  },
  {
    "name" = "B"
    "number" = "2"
    "description" = "Bla"
  },
]

  list_of_lists = [for a_map in local.test: 
            [a_map["name"], a_map["number"], a_map["description"]]]
    
}
```

which gives:

```
[
  [
    "A",
    "1",
    "Bla",
  ],
  [
    "B",
    "2",
    "Bla",
  ],
]
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question it's not clear whether you're asking how to solve this problem in the Terraform language or in Python -- you only mentioned Terraform in the question body, but you tagged it "python" and used Python syntax to show the tuples.

Others have already shown how to do this in Python, so just in case you were asking about Terraform the following is a Terraform equivalent:

```
locals {
  input = [
    {
      "name" = "A"
      "number" = "1"
      "description" = "Bla"
    },
    {
      "name" = "B"
      "number" = "2"
      "description" = "Bla"
    },
  ]

  list_of_tuples = tolist([
    for e in local.input : [e.name, e.number, e.description]
  ])
}
```

A tuple in Terraform is a kind of sequence type where the length is fixed and each element can have its own specified type. It's the sequence equivalent of an object, whereas a list corresponds with a map.

When evaluating the `list_of_tuples` expression above, Terraform will first construct a tuple of tuples (because `[]` brackets construct tuples) and then convert the *outer* tuple to be a list with [`tolist`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/tolist.html). The final type of `list_of_tuples` would therefore be the following, if written in [Terraform's type constraint syntax](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/type-constraints.html):

```
list(tuple([string, number, string]))
```